# How can I make a method variable available to inherited subclass?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Trying to invoke a method variable of superclass in the subclass.Is this possible, If possible, is it a good practice or design?

I have written an example code to execute the flow. Below is the code

```
class bar_for_foo_mixin():
    def __init__(self):
        self.z =0

    def bar(self, q):
        x=2
        y=8
        bar_for_foo_mixin.z= x+y+q
        print(bar_for_foo_mixin.z)

    def extented_bar(self):
        self.bar(10)


class myfoo(bar_for_foo_mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myfoo, self).__init__()
        print("hello",self.z)


class oldFoo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = bar_for_foo_mixin()

        self.var.bar(10)
```

Now how can I make the Z value and make it useful in the subclass? But If Call method `extended_bar()` in the subclass the above code works fine, But is there any way to store the method variable of superclass and use it in the subclass?

**A third class call bar method.**
Expected output to print. The Z vaue should store the computations done in the superclass method `bar`.

```
hello 20
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the `__init__` method of the subclass call the base class' `__init__` method via the `super()` function:

```
class myfoo(bar_for_foo_mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("hello",self.z)
```

Moreover, since `z` is initialized as an instance variable, your `bar` function should update it as a variable bound to `self` instead of the class:

```
def bar(self, q):
    x=2
    y=8
    self.z= x+y+q
    print(self.z)
```

Comment: It prints hello 0. But I want the calculation part stored . It should print hello 20 .

Comment: But nothing is calling the `bar` and `extented_bar` methods at all. Did you mean to call them from the `__init__` method of the base class?